# Trying to Plot Closest Words Using TSNE in Word2Vec model

Tags: python, word2vec, tsne

I can't figure out why I keep getting a ValueError messsage with the following code:

```
def display_closestwords_tsnescatterplot(test_model, word):
    
    arr = np.empty((0,300), dtype='f')
    word_labels = [word]

    # get close words
    close_words = test_model.wv.similar_by_word(word)
    
    # add the vector for each of the closest words to the array
    arr = np.append(arr, np.array(test_model.wv[word]), axis=0)
    for wrd_score in close_words:
        wrd_vector = test_model[wrd_score[0]]
        word_labels.append(wrd_score[0])
        arr = np.append(arr, (np.array(test_model.wv[word])), axis=0)
        
    # find tsne coords for 2 dimensions
    tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=0)
    np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
    Y = tsne.fit_transform(arr)

    x_coords = Y[:, 0]
    y_coords = Y[:, 1]
    # display scatter plot
    plt.scatter(x_coords, y_coords)

    for label, x, y in zip(word_labels, x_coords, y_coords):
        plt.annotate(label, xy=(x, y), xytext=(0, 0), textcoords='offset points')
    plt.xlim(x_coords.min()+0.00005, x_coords.max()+0.00005)
    plt.ylim(y_coords.min()+0.00005, y_coords.max()+0.00005)
    plt.show()

display_closestwords_tsnescatterplot(test_model, 'river')
```

Here is the error message:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[99], line 1
----> 1 display_closestwords_tsnescatterplot(test_model, 'river')

Cell In[98], line 10, in display_closestwords_tsnescatterplot(test_model, word)
      7 close_words = test_model.wv.similar_by_word(word)
      9 # add the vector for each of the closest words to the array
---> 10 arr = np.append(arr, (np.array(test_model.wv[word])), axis=0)
     11 for wrd_score in close_words:
     12     wrd_vector = test_model[wrd_score[0]]

File <__array_function__ internals>:180, in append(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:5444, in append(arr, values, axis)
   5442     values = ravel(values)
   5443     axis = arr.ndim-1
-> 5444 return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)

File <__array_function__ internals>:180, in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)
```

Note: I've tried some code from other related questions but all of the code is outdated per gensim updates so I'd rather stick with this one and see if I can make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a batch dimension to the word vector in your `np.append` statement when using the `axis` keyword, [as discussed in the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html). A fast fix is to simply wrap your appended variable in a list:

```py
arr = np.append(arr, [np.array(test_model.wv[word])], axis=0)
```

Comment: I have tried this and I get the same error.